# Proving a group $G$ with presentation $\langle a,b\mid ab\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Given that $ab=e$, we know $b =a^{-1}$. Since $G = \langle a,b\rangle$ this implies $\langle a,b\rangle=\langle a,a^{-1}\rangle=\langle a\rangle=G$ (as elements that generate the group). The presentation rewritten in terms of $a$ is trivial, i.e. $\langle a,a^{-1}\mid aa^{-1}=e\rangle$, so $G$ is a free group on the generator $a$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have just learned about group presentations and I am also wondering if there is a general method for identifying the isomorphism classes of a group given its presentation.

Comment: No there is no general method, because most questions that you might ask, such as "is this group finite?" have been proved to be undecidable.

Comment: Does this mean the conclusion of the proof is wrong

Comment: No, not at all - it is correct. There are lots of methods that can be applied to particular  presentations. I was just saying that there is no uinform method that can be applied to all presentations.